# HMM Bayesian vs. non-Bayesian

Tags: time-series, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I aim to use Hidden Markov Model for regime detection in time series. My question might be a little too blurry:

in which cases it is crucial to use Bayesian version of HMM and in which cases it is not?

Also, am I right that if the amount of data grows, then both methods will tend to be very similar (which is true in a Bayesian statistics under some mild conditions)?

Comment: There's two parts to this question: 1) what is the appropriate frequentist analogue of Bayesian HMM? The answer is a latent variables analysis. And 2) when do we use Bayesian vs. Frequentist analyses? I *expect* the answer is the normal discourse: pros: shrinkage, posterior probability, informative priors, cons: hard to find non-informative prior if it exists, no significance testing, no confidence intervals.

Comment: Dear @ AdamO, thank you! Is my last statement correct? The one about the similarity.